# c++: use map as value of another map

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, text-mining, stdmap

I just wonder if I can use a "complicated" map as the value of another map. I have self-defined several structs as follow:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> pattern;
typedef std::map<int, std::vector<pattern>> dimPatternsMap;
typedef std::map<int, dimPatternsMap> supportDimMapMap;
```

OK let me explain these things...`pattern` is a vector of strings. For the "smaller" map `dimPatternsMap`, the key is an integer which is the dimension of pattern (the size of that vector containing strings) and the value is vector containing patterns (which is a vector of vectors...).

The "bigger" map `supportDimMapMap` also use an integer as the key value, but use `dimPatternsMap` as its value. The key means "support count".

Now I begin to construct this "complicated" map:

```
supportDimMapMap currReverseMap;
pattern p = getItFromSomePlace();  //I just omit the process I got pattern and its support
int support = getItFromSomePlaceToo();

if(currReverseMap.find(support) == currReverseMap.end()) {
    dimPatternsMap newDpm;

    std::vector<pattern> newPatterns;
    newPatterns.push_back(currPattern);
    newDpm[dim] = newPatterns;

    currReverseMap[support] = newDpm;

} else{
    dimPatternsMap currDpm = currReverseMap[support];

    if(currDpm.find(dim) == currDpm.end()) {
        std::vector<pattern> currDimPatterns;
        currDimPatterns.push_back(currPattern);

        currDpm[dim] = currDimPatterns;
    } else {
        currDpm[dim].push_back(currPattern);
    }
}
```

Forgive me the code is really a mass...

But then as I want to traverse the map like:

```
for(supportDimMapMap::iterator iter = currReverseMap.begin(); iter != currReverseMap.end(); ++iter) {
        int support = iter->first;
        dimPatternsMap dpm = iter->second;

        for(dimPatternsMap::iterator ittt = dpm.begin(); ittt != dpm.end(); ++ittt) {
            int dim = ittt->first;
            std::vector<pattern> patterns = ittt->second;
            int s = patterns.size();
        }
}
```

I found the value `s` is always 1, which means that for each unique support value and for each dimension of that support value, there is only one pattern! But as I debug my code in the map constructing process, I indeed found that the size is not 1 - I actually added the new patterns into the map successfully...But when it comes to traversing, all the sizes become 1 and I don't know why...

Any suggestions or explanations will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: You don't actually need the `find` calls at all, since `operator[]` will default-construct a value whenever the key is new, and a default-constructed container is an empty container.  That whole block of code could be rewritten just `currReverseMap[support][dim].push_back(pattern);`.

Comment: I guess I should say a default-constructed container is *usually* empty.  `std::array<T,N>` is the notable counterexample.

Comment: I am still unsure whether I actually understand that code correctly, but I am fairly sure that there is nothing wrong with your output: As far as I can tell you are always adding a vector of size 1 to your map, so your s should always be 1 - your total map size has more elements (although you don't even seem to be adding anything in the `else` block) but at the very bottom it should always be size 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dimPatternsMap currDpm = currReverseMap[support];
```

`currDpm` is a copy of `currReverseMap[support]`.  It is not the same object.  So then when you make changes to `currDpm`, nothing within `currReverseMap` changes.

On the other hand, if you use a reference:

```
dimPatternsMap& currDpm = currReverseMap[support];
```

then `currDpm` and `currReverseMap[support]` really are the same object, so later statements using `currDpm` will really be changing a value within `currReverseMap`.

There are a few other places where your code could benefit from references too.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: you should use a reference in your else:

```
dimPatternsMap& currDpm = currReverseMap[support];
```

Your current code creates a copy instead of using the original map.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
dimPatternsMap currDpm = currReverseMap[support];
```

Based on the code following it, it wants to read like this:

```
dimPatternsMap& currDpm = currReverseMap[support];
```

Without the `&` you modify a copy of the entry rather than the existing entry.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is making several copies of the objects underneath, try using more references and iterators (`find()` already gives you an element if it was found, for example).

For example, `dimPatternsMap currDpm = currReverseMap[support];` actually makes a copy of a map in your structure and adds an element to it (not to the original). Try using a reference instead.